# Docker and microservices

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, laradock

I am developing a system using microservices, for myself to learn new technology. One service on php (laravel) + postgres, the other on nodejs (express) + mongo, and another on php (symfony) + with other postgres server, I want to wrap all of this services in the docker. I looked at the decision https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock, but there is only one container workspace, and one container to postgres, how do I correct tune docker?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for inaccurate question, I want use dockers, for emulate a situation when three services with it's databases on different servers

Comment: You can just use docker-compose to prepare what you want. You can create as many containers as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/LaraDock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) in the link you provided, you can see that they have split up everything into separate docker containers.

If you want more than one of any of the containers listed you use [docker-compose scale](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/) to create duplicates.